# How to smoothly move mouse cursor with Java?

Tags: java, android, awtrobot

I'm trying to use the Robot class to move the mouse pointer based on accelerometer readings I'm getting from my android device via bluetooth. The problem is that the mouse cursor moves in steps. I need a way to move it smoothly, like physically dragging the pointer. Here's what I have so far

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
        if(serialPortEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine = input.readLine();
                String[] values = inputLine.split(",");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(values[0])*(-1);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(values[1])*(-1);
                mouse.moveMouse(x, y);
                //System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
}
```

Here the mouse pointer moves in smaller or bigger steps depending on how much the phone is tilted. But I want it to move faster or slower.

Comment: What is the value of `values`? You might be loosing accuracy when parsing to `int`? I guess it depends on whether or not `moveMouse(x, y)` only takes 'int's as parameters

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called **interpolation**, and there are probably a bunch of results on google for it. But the basics are that you need to figure out which positions are **between** your start and end positions, and move through them over time.

Alternatively, it looks like you might be able to simply scale your input values down.